# Cannot navigate to ViewController on RowSelect

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have UITableView

Here is code of it

```
public partial class WishlistTableController : UITableViewController
{
    public WishlistTableController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        List<WishlistDatabaseModel> WishlistTableItems = ExperienceMethods.GetWishlistItems();
        WishlistTableView.Source = new WishlistSource(WishlistTableItems, this, this.NavigationController);
        WishlistTableView.RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
        WishlistTableView.EstimatedRowHeight = 80f;
        WishlistTableView.ReloadData();
    }
}
```

Also I have DataSource for this TableView, where I need to go to another ViewController on RowSelect.

But when I click on row, I get this error

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>     at TravelApp.DataSources.WishlistSource+d__7.MoveNext () [0x000bb] in /Users/evhenijsuhomlyn/Documents/GitHub/TravelAppiOS/TravelApp/DataSources/WishlistSource.cs:53

I checked controllers and Storuboard id's, all okay.

Here is code of it

```
public class WishlistSource : UITableViewSource
{
    private UINavigationController primNav { get; }
    readonly List<WishlistDatabaseModel> _tableItems;
    private WishlistTableController owner;

    public WishlistSource(List<WishlistDatabaseModel> items, WishlistTableController owner,
        UINavigationController nav)
    {
        _tableItems = items;
        this.owner = owner;
        primNav = nav;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {

        if (_tableItems.Count == 0)
        {
            var noDataLabel = new UILabel
            {
                Text = "No Experiences at your location at this time. Try to change destination",
                TextColor = UIColor.Black,
                TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center,
                LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap,
                Lines = 0
            };
            tableview.BackgroundView = noDataLabel;
            tableview.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
            return _tableItems.Count;
        }

        tableview.BackgroundView = null;
        tableview.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine;
        return _tableItems.Count;
    }
    public override async void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var selectedExperience = await ExperienceMethods.GetSelectedTour(_tableItems[indexPath.Row].id);
        if (selectedExperience == "Saved")
        {
            MyExperienceDetailViewController MyExperienceDetailController = primNav.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("MyExperienceDetailViewController") as MyExperienceDetailViewController;
            primNav.PushViewController(MyExperienceDetailController, true);
        }
        tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, true);
    }
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("wishlistcell", indexPath) as WishlistCell;
        WishlistDatabaseModel item = _tableItems[indexPath.Row];
        cell.UpdateCell(item);
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Where can be problem?

Comment: If it happens when you click on a row, it is happening in your RowSelected method. What is the value of "selectedExperience" when you hit the "if" statement ?

Comment: It's "Saved" as breakpoint tells @Miiite

Comment: Which line is 53? Is it the PushViewController? Is `primNav` set? Does `MyExperienceDetailController` have a value?

Comment: 53 line is `MyExperienceDetailViewController MyExperienceDetailController = primNav.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("MyExperienceDetailViewController") as MyExperienceDetailViewController;`

What you mean by have a value? @Cheesebaron

Comment: So I guess the ViewController fails to be created. Have you set an ID on your storyboard ?

Comment: Yes, id is setted in Storyboard @Miiite

Comment: So when you hit the line primNav.PushViewController(MyExperienceDetailController, true); , the content of your property "MyExperienceDetailController" is not null ?

Comment: It's fails on `MyExperienceDetailViewController MyExperienceDetailController = primNav.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("MyExperienceDetailViewController") as MyExperienceDetailViewController;`

I tried to navigate to other controllers. Same thing @Miiite

Comment: And the value of primNav.Storyboard, matches the storyboard file your viewcontroller is in ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187431/discussion-between-eugene-sukh-and-miiite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use another method to create your Storyboard.

```
var storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("YourStoryboard", null); 
var viewController = storyboard.InstantiateViewController(nameof(YourViewController)); 
NavigationController.PushViewController(viewController, true);
```